# Kendo format string puts literal '?' in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, number-formatting

We allow users to specify custom symbols as part of the number formats they see in our software. We are using Kendo's formatting capability to incorporate these symbols as part of our format strings. For example, we might have a format string like:

```
var format = "\\$0.00\\/\\h\\r;(\\$0.00\\/\\h\\r)";
kendo.toString(-1.7, format); // ($1.70/hr)
```

Note the use of backslashes to escape literal characters in the format string. This seems to work well, except when the `?` character is used. Here's an example:

```
var format = "\\?\\x0";
kendo.toString(100, format); // returns "x?100", but I would expect "?x100"
```

What's going on here? Is this a bug in Kendo or desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles across this question, there's a [discussion about it in the Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-format-string-puts-literal-'-'-in-the-wrong-place) which I assume the OP opened. This led to [opening an issue on github](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/2326).
[**Edit:**]
The github bug was opened with this information:
**Bug report**
Kendo format string does not put the literal '?' in the correct place. This is not observable in every scenario. Escaping or not the literal '?' does not change the result is some scenarios.
**Reproduction of the problem**
The issue can be observed in the following Dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/avUne

**Environment**
Browser: all

There was no update since 18 Oct 2016, up to the time these words have been typed.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).